# Sphinx Search exclude empty item from result

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

I have an index abc with field1, field2, field3 and field4 . For field4 some data is empty .

Ex :

```
select field1, field4  from abc  \
      order by field4 asc limit 3;
```

Result:

```
+------+---------------+
| id   | field4        |
+------+---------------+
|  142 |               |
|  149 |               |
|  154 |    test       |
+------+---------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

But i want to exclude all empty item for  field4. How to do that ?

The Result should be :

```
+------+---------------+
| id   | field4        |
+------+---------------+
|  154 |    test       |
+------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory can do

```
select field1, field4 from abc where field4 != ''
```

As can now filter string attributes. Having said that, not sure filtering on empty values work.

... So would have to arrange the attribute to contain something else instead of empty. eg when building the index, replace true empty with the word 'empty' or similar.

```
select field1, field4 from abc where field4 != 'empty'
```

Comment: sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting CONST_INT (or 4 other tokens) near '"" order by field4 asc limit 3'

Comment: exactly, empty strings don't actully work. which is why would need to arrange to use something else other than a real empty string.

Comment: Contracting the sphinx index by inner join with 4 tables  so some time the table will not have an item for the query. This entry in index will have an empty value. As i cant change the indexing logic, Can i have any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: If i **replace true empty with the word 'empty'** full text search will catch this "Empty" as a data in index right ? :(

Comment: If you can't change the index, then probably not. Although if you happen to have index_field_lengths enabled, it should be possible to use the lenght of the field to exclude empty items.